# Tabula-py: The output file is empty

Tags: python, tabula

I have converted the image to pdf using img2pdf library in python, and then trying to read that pdf using tabula-py. Although the pdf file is created successfully with its contents yet, tabula-py is not able to read the content. I have tried a lottt of resources whih didn't help. Any sort of help is highly appreciated.

EDIT1: I have used the code from the following link to convert image to PDF- https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-image-to-pdf-using-img2pdf-module/amp/

And then, I am using tabula-py to read the output PDF as-
tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all')

Comment: Please share your code and any error messages you encountered.

Comment: There are no errors @Roy Cohen. I get the output as 'The output file is empty.'